# BitLocker stuck during partial partition encryption

Tags: bitlocker, windows-server-2012-r2, refs

I wanted **BitLocker** to encrypt an REFS partition on a VHDX (virtual HDD), and it is now **stuck** at ~70%, asking for `chkdsk /r`. 
I can't run `chkdsk` because REFS doesn't support (and doesn't need) that, but I also **can't decrypt the partition** because I get an error message: `A device attached to the system is not functioning.`

A possible cause or error could be that the size of the VHDX was increased during encryption, but I'm not 100% certain this was done.
I tried to copy the data to another drive (unecrypted, NTFS), but **read operations on the half-encrypted partition always fail after about 50 MB to 150 MB**, meaning I can't copy any files larger than that (which is about 90% of the files). Using TeraCopy led to the same read error, and splitting the files with HJ Split didn't work (error on splitting).

Can you help me get my data off the drive (#1 priority) or fix BitLocker?